# Installed Visual SVN Server, except I get this message when do SVN Check Out

Tags: svn, installation, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

So I installed VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN client.  And I created a user on the SVN Server, and now I went to a new folder c:\src, right click and choose  "SVN Checkout...", and it always gives me this message

```
Checkout from https://bookroom:8443/svn, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included

Error: OPTIONS of 'https://bookroom:8443/svn': 200 OK (https://bookroom:8443)  

Finished!
```

bookroom is the name of my PC...

any one know how to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing that https://bookroom:8443/svn isn't a valid Subversion repository.

You should have created one or more repositories that fall underneath /svn so the url you want to checkout from would be something like **https://bookroom:8443/svn/reponame**

For example, here's the VisualSVN manager on my machine:

[image: VisualSVN Manager]

Let's say my main url is https://mark:8443/svn.  You can see how I have one repository called *adhoc* so I would checkout the url **https://mark:8443/svn/adhoc**.

Comment: so initially, it had the "Repositories"... and that is not a valid repository?  I need to create new repository and then will have the first valid repository?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to have at least one repository created in the management tool.

Comment: wow great, it works!  is it that usually we just want 1 repository, but if we have too many files and they belong to a totally different project, then we can create another repository?  i think if we have too many repositories, they can be messy to handle too.

Comment: There's a lot of discussion about that.  At home, I just have a single repository and lots of folders within that repository for different projects.

At work though, we have different repositories for different types of work and/or clients (just to make it a little easier to keep track of).

Comment: For example, at home, I might have /svn/adhoc/Project1 and /svn/adhoc/Project2 and so on.  There's really no limit to how many folders you create within a project so it's pretty easy to keep things organized.

Comment: Just spent 10 minutes frothing at the mouth because my shiney new VisualSVN server didn't appear to be working. I forgot the /svn/. Thank you!